# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out with AWS Instance

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, zend-framework, amazon-rds

I am working on a web application using Zend Framework as a backend platform hosted on AWS instance.

After certain amount of usage, it generates an error which states that

> "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out" Error.

It occurs only on production environment.

On Production site - we have two EC2 instances and enabled load balancer too.

The above error is not generated upon every request, It is generated randomly after certain amount of usage - I had checked CPU utilization at moment when error occurred and its amount was only 3% along with database utilization upto (1% - 3%).

[image]

Comment: Seems like it's the database that times out. Since you're having a load balancer, I'm guessing you have a separate DB server?

Comment: Yes, Have separate DB Server.
You are correct, it is loosing database connection, but not able to find reason for same.

Comment: You say that you've checked the CPU utilization, was that on the DB server? Does it get too many requests or similar?

Comment: Yes, I am using RDS, So can check there.

Comment: Anything new here?

Comment: I have Sucuri firewall which was causing this issue.
After deleting its Sucuri Cache I didn't face issue afterwards. 

So, I suggest to delete Sucuri cache in timely manner or create a cron which will delete Sucuri cache.